# MIME::Lite, send_by_smtp just working locally not on server

Tags: nginx, smtp, mime

I added the option of sending email from my website but it doesnt work on the staging and production server(nginx).
It does work on localhost.
I added their ip address to the `/postfix/main.cf` file it worked once and did not work after that. Why?

```
my $mailer = MIME::Lite->new(
                From       => $from,
                To         => $to,
                "Reply-To" => $from,
                Subject    => "Sharing this post : $sub",
                Type       => 'text/plain',
                Encoding   => '8bit',
                Data       => $body
        );
        eval { $mailer->send_by_smtp('mail.holla.org'); };
        if($@) {
                #my @errors = $mailer->errstr;
                #$.error(@errors);
                $.error('<span style="color:#ce4c4c;">ERROR ($@):</span> your comment could not be sent at this time, please try again in a few minutes.')
        }
}
```

**update after adding debugging**

```
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>> MIME::Lite::SMTP
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>   Net::SMTP(2.31)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>     Net::Cmd(2.29)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>       Exporter(5.64_03)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>       IO::Socket(1.32)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>         IO::Handle(1.31)
MIME::Lite::SMTP: Unexpected EOF on command channel at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/MIME/Lite.pm line 2874.
```

**line 2874**

```
  my $smtp = MIME::Lite::SMTP->new( $hostname, %opts )
  or Carp::croak "SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: $!\n";
```

Comment: Run the above script from command line with smtp debbuging turned on. `eval { $mailer->send_by_smtp('mail.holla.org', Debug=>2 ); };`

Comment: needed to add space between ip addresses in postfix